# How do I call a macro function in a global template/add-in from another template?

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word, ms-office, add-in

First, I am a VBA newbie. So please pardon my ignorance.

I have a global template that I installed in the Word startup folder.

The global template has some macros that I would like to access. But I can't figure out how to access the macro.

I tried to use `Application.Run`, but that doesn't work (or at least I'm doing it wrong). I keep getting Runtime Error 424.

I also tried to use something like `Call globaltemplatename.modulename.functionname` but that doesn't work either.

I also tried to simply call the function but then it says that the function/sub is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

LOL... um... nvm... I found out why...

I didn't create a reference in the template that I was calling from...

Well...in case anybody else runs into this problem, you have to open the template (not the global template) and then go to Tools > References in the VB editor. And then check the  project name of the global template.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Great to hear it is sorted. You can accept your own answer by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down arrows on this answer.  When you have a chance, take an opportunity to read through the FAQ at http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 1):

```
sTemp = Application.Run ("modulename.functionname")
```

The entire string is in double quotes.

Word does not want the templates name - leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

Even more Word do not let you use more than *ModuleName.ProcName*. Otherwise a runtime error will be thrown.