MS Word Macro Editor - Referencing a Sub from a different Project from within Normal() Module
I am trying to reference subs that are in the Word Document Project from normal ()
The screenshot should explain it best but…

This is in Normal / Modules / New Macro
Sub Macro1()

    Project.Module1.test

End Sub



This is in Project / Modules / Modules1
Public Sub test()

    MsgBox "This is a subroutine in Temp"

End Sub


I've tried a number of variations, but I always get “424” Object Not Found” Error
What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance. - CES



Maybe look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227903/how-do-i-call-a-macro-function-in-a-global-template-add-in-from-another-template
